# Problema com Manipulação de HTML com PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Galera na   parte do `echo <p class="play">$row[/"email/"] </p>`    da um erro de sintaxe

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'play' (T_STRING), expecting ','
>   or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\a\index.php on line 20

nao reconhece a classe que eu dou pra ele, sem ela não consigo formatar os resultados.

```
            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 

            $sql = "SELECT email FROM news";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo  "<p class="play"> $row[\"email\"]</p>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
            $conn->close();
            ?>
```

Comment: quase que vc não erra, colocou as contra barras no `$row[\"email\"]` ao invés de colocar no `class="play"`.  uma solução `echo  "<p class=\"play\"> $row["email"]</p>";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É necessário usar a barra para escapar as aspas duplas na class:

```
echo  "<p class=\"play\"> {$row["email"]}</p>";
```

Ou você pode simplesmente trocar as aspas duplas por aspas simples

```
    echo  "<p class='play'> {$row['email']}</p>";
```

Quando for utilizar um array dentro de uma string, é sempre bom encapsular a variável com {}.

Comment: Cara Obrigado pela dicas, não sei voce sabe mas ia salvar demais+. Chamando esse echo $row 'email' ta pegando todos do banco de dados. Como posso pegar apenas uma das linhas randomicamente? <3 obrigado demais

Comment: O jeito mais fácil e rápido é trocando o seu sql por: "SELECT email FROM news ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1".

Comment: Se a resposta funcionou, marca ela como certa para ajudar outros usuários com a mesma dúvida futuramente :)

Comment: Sim, realmente essa consulta `SELECT email FROM news ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`  irá retornar um dado aleatório da tabela, mas se num script PHP você precisar, por exemplo, executar a mesma query em um intervalo muito pequeno de tempo ele irá retornar sempre os mesmos dados! O problema que ocorre é que a maioria dos servidores tem um tipo de clock interno que é utilizado para escolher a entrada aleatória da tabela. Se abrir uma página que tenha essa query e em seguida abrir a mesma página com outro browser, isso irá funcionar sem problemas, afinal você estará abrindo outra sessão do browser.